# How do I view array type data in Data Viewer in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run `View()` to view the data after creating the array, I cannot view the data in tabular form. Instead I see the *name*, *type* and *values* of this data as seen in the screenshot. What do I need to do to view the data in the *Data Viewer Panel*?

[image]

```r
a<-array(c('HI','all','!!'),dim = c(3,5,5))

View(a)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how you can use Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The Data Viewer in the RStudio IDE

In R programming, the `View()` command prints the output to the *Data Viewer* <sub>1</sub> panel. *Data Viewer* panel is only compatible with data in data frame format; *not compatible for printing arrays* <sub>2</sub>.

```r
data(iris)
View(iris)
```

After converting an array to a matrix in the R programming language, you can display it in the Data Viewer using the `View()` command. For example:

```r
a <- array(c('HI','all','!!'),dim = c(3,5,5))
View(apply(a, 3, c))
```

[image]

---

##### Print Values

You can use the `print()` command to print the contents of a value to the console.

```r
a <- array(c('HI','all','!!'),dim = c(3,5,5))
print(a)
```

---

<sub>1. [Using The Data Viewer in the RStudio IDE](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer-in-the-RStudio-IDE)</sub>

<sub>2. [R Language Vectors vs. Arrays vs. Lists vs. Matrices vs. Data Frames](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/r-language-vectors-vs-arrays-vs-lists-vs-matrices-vs-data-frames/)</sub>

Comment: Still the same issue with View(), there is nothing reflecting in the data view panel after executing the function View().

Comment: I tried view() with matrices, it works

Comment: Sorry, good reminder. I edited the post. After converting the array to matrix it worked.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!!